# Data missing from document during web-scrape in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to access the second iframe url in the first iframe urls body: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEWf8.png). However my code will only show the contents of the document with the body missing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Getting the bookeoUrl
myUrl = 'https://www.impulseedmonton.com/book-now/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users||EAS12\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(myUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
driver.quit()
frame = soup.findAll('iframe')
frameUrl = frame[0]['src']
driver.get(src)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lmxl')
print(soup)
```

It seems the body is missing from the webpage of the second soup. I have been working on this for 2 days and just can't understand why.

Comment: Can you get the content of other tags besides <body>?

Comment: Yes i can. I get body as well but it just shows margin thats all.